# How to generate a core dump in Linux on a segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, coredump, tcsh

I have a process in Linux that's getting a segmentation fault.  How can I tell it to generate a core dump when it fails?

Comment: How to view it aftewards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-do-i-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb-when-it-has-command-line-pa

Answer (score 278, accepted):

This depends on what shell you are using.  If you are using bash, then the ulimit command controls several settings relating to program execution, such as whether you should dump core.  If you type

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

then that will tell bash that its programs can dump cores of any size.  You can specify a size such as 52M instead of unlimited if you want, but in practice this shouldn't be necessary since the size of core files will probably never be an issue for you.

In tcsh, you'd type

```
limit coredumpsize unlimited
```

Comment: I am sorry, but is this really answer your question? you asked how to generate, but it say how to set the limits

Comment: @lzprgmr: To clarify: the reason why core dumps are not generated by default is that the limit is not set and/or set to 0, which prevents the core from being dumped.  By setting a limit of unlimited, we guarantee that core dumps can always be generated.

Comment: This [link](http://www.randombugs.com/linux/core-dumps-linux.html) goes deeper and gives some more options to enable generation of core dumps in linux. The only drawback is that some commands/settings are left unexplained.

Comment: On bash 4.1.2(1)-release limits such as 52M cannot be specified, resulting in a invalid number error message. The man page tells that "Values are in 1024-byte increments".

Comment: Well I had a "small" OpenGL project, that once did some weird thing, and caused X-server crash. When I logged back, I saw a cute little 17 GB core file (on a 25 GB partition). It's definitely a good idea to keep the core file's size limited :)

Comment: I have a question. I don't want to set mine to unlimited. How do I know how large of a coredump  should allow?

Comment: @PolarisUser: If you wanted to make sure your partition doesn't get eaten, I recommend setting a limit of something like 1 gig.  That should be big enough to handle any reasonable core dump, while not threatening to use up all of your remaining hard drive space.

Comment: I want to echo setting a limit for coredumpsize, as someone who just had to clean up a couple hundred 20G core dumps.

Comment: attention: it is not persisted after login user quits, at least on CentOS, you have to edit /etc/security/limits.conf if you want so.

Comment: and remember to put this in in .bashrc so that you wont need to do this all the time.

Answer (score 69):

As explained above the real question being asked here is how to enable core dumps on a system where they are not enabled. That question is answered here.

If you've come here hoping to learn how to generate a core dump for a hung process, the answer is

```
gcore <pid>
```

if gcore is not available on your system then

```
kill -ABRT <pid>
```

Don't use kill -SEGV as that will often invoke a signal handler making it harder to diagnose the stuck process

Comment: I think it's far more likely that `-ABRT` will invoke a signal handler than `-SEGV`, as an abort is more likely to be recoverable than a segfault. (If you handle a segfault, normally it'll just trigger again as soon as your handler exits.) A better choice of signal for generating a core dump is `-QUIT`.

Answer (score 50):

To check where the core dumps are generated, run:

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern
```

or:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

where `%e` is the process name and `%t` the system time. You can change it in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reloading by `sysctl -p`.

If the core files are not generated (test it by: `sleep 10 &` and `killall -SIGSEGV sleep`), check the limits by: `ulimit -a`.

If your core file size is limited, run:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

to make it unlimited.

Then test again, if the core dumping is successful, you will see “(core dumped)” after the segmentation fault indication as below:

> Segmentation fault: 11  (core dumped)

See also: [core dumped - but core file is not in current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065912/55075)

---

#### Ubuntu

In Ubuntu the core dumps are handled by [*Apport*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) and can be located in `/var/crash/`. However, it is disabled by default in stable releases.

For more details, please check: [Where do I find the core dump in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/966407/78223).

#### macOS

For macOS, see: [How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412156/55075)

Comment: For Ubuntu, to quickly revert to normal behavior (dumping a core file in the current directory), simply stop the apport service with "sudo service apport stop".   Also note that if you are running within docker, that setting is controlled on the host system and not within the container.

Comment: Instead of disabling apport every time it could be more lasting just to *uninstall* apport (ignoring the recommendation dependency) since the service adds no value for developers.

Answer (score 30):

What I did at the end was attach gdb to the process before it crashed, and then when it got the segfault I executed the `generate-core-file` command.  That forced generation of a core dump.

Comment: How did you attach gdb to the process ?

Comment: To answer to Ritwik G, to attach a process to gdb, simply launch gdb and enter 'attach <pid>' where <pid> is the pid number of the process you want to attach.

Comment: (abbreviated as `ge`)

Comment: If they have a new question, they should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370972/how-to-attach-a-process-in-gdb) instead of asking in a comment.

Comment: Weird thing is I already set `ulimit -c` to `unlimited`, but the core file is stilled no created, the `generate-core-file` file in gdb session does create the core file, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you could do it this way, this program is a demonstration of how to trap a segmentation fault and shells out to a debugger (this is the original code used under `AIX`) and prints the stack trace up to the point of a segmentation fault. You will need to change the `sprintf` variable to use `gdb` in the case of Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static void signal_handler(int);
static void dumpstack(void);
static void cleanup(void);
void init_signals(void);
void panic(const char *, ...);

struct sigaction sigact;
char *progname;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *s;
    progname = *(argv);
    atexit(cleanup);
    init_signals();
    printf("About to seg fault by assigning zero to *s\n");
    *s = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    return 0;
}

void init_signals(void) {
    sigact.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL);

    sigaddset(&sigact.sa_mask, SIGSEGV);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL);

    sigaddset(&sigact.sa_mask, SIGBUS);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL);

    sigaddset(&sigact.sa_mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL);

    sigaddset(&sigact.sa_mask, SIGHUP);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL);

    sigaddset(&sigact.sa_mask, SIGKILL);
    sigaction(SIGKILL, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL);
}

static void signal_handler(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGHUP) panic("FATAL: Program hanged up\n");
    if (sig == SIGSEGV || sig == SIGBUS){
        dumpstack();
        panic("FATAL: %s Fault. Logged StackTrace\n", (sig == SIGSEGV) ? "Segmentation" : ((sig == SIGBUS) ? "Bus" : "Unknown"));
    }
    if (sig == SIGQUIT) panic("QUIT signal ended program\n");
    if (sig == SIGKILL) panic("KILL signal ended program\n");
    if (sig == SIGINT) ;
}

void panic(const char *fmt, ...) {
    char buf[50];
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fprintf(stderr, buf);
    exit(-1);
}

static void dumpstack(void) {
    /* Got this routine from http://www.whitefang.com/unix/faq_toc.html
    ** Section 6.5. Modified to redirect to file to prevent clutter
    */
    /* This needs to be changed... */
    char dbx[160];

    sprintf(dbx, "echo 'where\ndetach' | dbx -a %d > %s.dump", getpid(), progname);
    /* Change the dbx to gdb */

    system(dbx);
    return;
}

void cleanup(void) {
    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    /* Do any cleaning up chores here */
}
```

You may have to additionally add a parameter to get gdb to dump the core as shown here in this blog [here](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/12/21/generating-core-files-from-gdb/).

Answer (score 17):

There are more things that may influence the generation of a core dump.  I encountered these:

- the directory for the dump must be writable.  By default this is the current directory of the process, but that may be changed by setting `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`.
- in some conditions, the kernel value in `/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable` may prevent the core to be generated.

There are more situations which may prevent the generation that are described in the man page - try `man core`.

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu 14.04

1. Check  core dump enabled:

   ```
   ulimit -a
   ```
2. One of the lines should be :

   ```
   core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
   ```
3. If not :

   `gedit ~/.bashrc` and add `ulimit -c unlimited` to end of file and save, re-run terminal.
4. Build your application with debug information :

   In Makefile `-O0  -g`
5. Run application that create core dump (core dump file with name ‘core’ should be created near application_name file):

   ```
   ./application_name
   ```
6. Run under gdb:

   ```
   gdb application_name core
   ```

Comment: In Step 3, How to 're-run' the terminal? Do you mean reboot?

Comment: @Naveen no, just close terminal and open new one, also seems you can just put `ulimit -c unlimited` in terminal for temporary solution, because only editing `~/.bashrc` require terminal restrart to changes make effect.

Answer (score 10):

In order to activate the core dump do the following:

1. In  `/etc/profile` comment the line:

   ```
   # ulimit -S -c 0 > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```
2. In `/etc/security/limits.conf` comment out the line:

   ```
   *               soft    core            0
   ```
3. execute the cmd `limit coredumpsize unlimited` and check it with cmd `limit`:

   ```
   # limit coredumpsize unlimited
   # limit
   cputime      unlimited
   filesize     unlimited
   datasize     unlimited
   stacksize    10240 kbytes
   coredumpsize unlimited
   memoryuse    unlimited
   vmemoryuse   unlimited
   descriptors  1024
   memorylocked 32 kbytes
   maxproc      528383
   #
   ```
4. to check if the corefile gets written you can kill the relating process with cmd `kill -s SEGV <PID>` (should not be needed, just in case no core file gets written this can be used as a check):

   ```
   # kill -s SEGV <PID>
   ```

Once the corefile has been written make sure to deactivate the coredump settings again in the relating files (1./2./3.) !

Answer (score 5):

Better to turn on core dump programmatically using system call `setrlimit`.

example:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

bool enable_core_dump(){    
    struct rlimit corelim;

    corelim.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
    corelim.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;

    return (0 == setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &corelim));
}
```

Comment: why is that better?

Comment: core file generated after crash, no need to `ulimit -c unlimited` in the command line environment, and then rerun the application.

Comment: I don't want a core dump every time it crashes, only when a user contacts me as the developer to look at it.  If it crashes 100 times, I don't need 100 core dumps to look at.

Comment: In tha case, better to use `ulimit -c unlimited`. Also you can compile with marco definition, application will not include `enable_core_dump` symbol if not define that macro when release, and you will get a core dump replace with debug version.

Comment: even if it's qualified by a macro, that still requires me to recompile if I want to generate a core dump, rather than simply executing a command in the shell before rerunning.

Comment: It's so convenient for developer to obtain a core dump file and more verbose debug information. In release version,  usually compiling with `-O2` and without `-g` , and debug information stripped or optimized,  and I control all debug options and core file dump using that marco definition in CMakeLists.txt or Makefile. You can have your own choice.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth mentioning that if you have a [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) set up, then things are a little bit different. The set up typically would have the core files be piped, by means of `core_pattern` sysctl value, through `systemd-coredump(8)`. The core file size rlimit would typically be configured as "unlimited" already.

It is then possible to retrieve the core dumps using `coredumpctl(1)`.

The storage of core dumps, etc. is configured by `coredump.conf(5)`. There are examples of how to get the core files in the coredumpctl man page, but in short, it would look like this:

Find the core file:

```
[vps@phoenix]~$ coredumpctl list test_me | tail -1
Sun 2019-01-20 11:17:33 CET   16163  1224  1224  11 present /home/vps/test_me
```

Get the core file:

```
[vps@phoenix]~$ coredumpctl -o test_me.core dump 16163
```

Answer (score 5):

**Ubuntu 19.04**

All other answers themselves didn't help me. But the following sum up did the job

Create `~/.config/apport/settings` with the following content:

```
[main]
unpackaged=true
```

(This tells apport to also write core dumps for custom apps)

check: `ulimit -c`. If it outputs 0, fix it with

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Just for in case restart apport:

```
sudo systemctl restart apport
```

Crash files are now written in `/var/crash/`. But you *cannot* use them with gdb. To use them with gdb, use

```
apport-unpack <location_of_report> <target_directory>
```

Further information:

- Some answers suggest changing `core_pattern`. Be aware, that that file might get overwritten by the apport service on restarting.
- Simply stopping apport did not do the job
- The `ulimit -c` value might get changed automatically while you're trying other answers of the web. Be sure to check it regularly during setting up your core dump creation.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47481884/6702598

Answer (score 5):

This is typically sufficient:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Note this will **not persist between ssh sections**! To add persistence:

```
echo '* soft core unlimited' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Now, if you're using Ubuntu, "apport" is probably running. Here's how to check:

```
sudo systemctl status apport.service
```

If it is, you'll probably find core dumps in one of these places:

```
/var/lib/apport/coredump 
/var/crash
```

## If you want to change the location of core dumps

Make sure that you have the **permissions** to create files and the **directory exists** in the directory you're sending a core dump to!

Here's an example. Note this will *not persist across reboots*:

```
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/coredumps/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t
mkdir /coredumps
```

Make sure that the process that's crashing has access to write to this. The easiest way would be an example like this:

```
chmod 777 /coredumps
```

## Test that core dumps works

```
> crash.c
gcc -Wl,--defsym=main=0 crash.c
./a.out
==output== Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If it doesn't say "core dumped" above, something isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

By default you will get a core file.   Check to see that the current directory of the process is writable, or no core file will be created.

Comment: By "current directory of the process" do you mean the $cwd at the time the process was run?
~/abc> /usr/bin/cat def

if cat crashes, is the current directory in question ~/abc or /usr/bin?

Comment: ~/abc.  Hmm, comments have to be 15 characters long!

Comment: This would be the current directory at the time of the SEGV.  Also, processes running with a different effective user and/or group than the real user/group will not write core files.