# Is there any way of finding the root cause of Google Chrome's "Aw, Snap" page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have a Javascript Library which powers the core of our main product. In the past couple of days, Google Chrome has been throwing the blue "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong" screen when I try to run this library.

The library runs fine on other browsers, and it also runs fine on all of my colleague's copies of Chrome.

What I'm looking for is some sort of log in Google Chrome that could point me in the right direction. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728483/how-to-get-more-info-when-the-aw-snap-screen-shows-up-in-chrome

Comment: I did try to find a similar question before I posted, but I appeared to miss that one. That being said- the last answer on that question was over three years ago. Maybe there have been advances since then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get more info when the "Aw Snap" screen shows up in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728483/how-to-get-more-info-when-the-aw-snap-screen-shows-up-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with JavaScript, my guess is that your JavaScript VM reached the maximum allocated memory which can generate an *Aw-snap* website.

This can be easily checked by running *DevTools* and checking in *Memory* tab. If that's the case, the code should pause automatically just before the potential out-of-memory crash.

To debug this, you can run the sampling profile to record memory allocations.

Related:

- [How to determine what is causing Chrome to show the “Aw, Snap” dialogue](https://superuser.com/q/607563/87805)
- [How to get more info when the "Aw Snap" screen shows up in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728483/55075)
- [Is there any memory limit for Google Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620041/55075)
- [Max memory usage of a chrome process (tab) & how do I increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17491022/55075)