# Max memory usage of a chrome process (tab) & how do I increase it?

Tags: http, google-chrome, memory, ssl, https

I am running several thousand https clients through chrome on one tab, I seem to be hitting a limit in the browser, when I check task manager the chrome process for that tab is using a whopping 897MB so I am assuming there is some sort of limit (900MB~).

Are there any chrome wizards around that could explain this? Also it would be ideal if I could increase the max limit so I am able to run more clients through a single tab.

Comment: I think it has to something with chrome being 32bit. Downloading the beta that is 64bit seems to allow tabs to go up to ~1.5-1.7 gig.

Comment: Chrome's limit per tab is… no actually a thing (anymore?).  It has multiple tabs per process, but it does a piss-poor job at detecting/determining that it needs to migrate a tab into another process and/or a poor job at actual migration (maybe it can't even move a tab out into its own process).

I have 128 GB RAM, and I run into "Out of memory" on occasion, and in Resource Monitor (Win10) it's obvious that there's RAM up for grabs.

Answer (score 40):

By default v8 has a memory limit of 512MB on 32-bit systems, and 1.4GB on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by setting `--max_old_space_size` to a maximum of 1024 (1 GB) on 32-bit and 4096 (4GB) on 64-bit. You should be able to set this parameter when launching Chrome from a shell in Linux, or as an argument to the shortcut path in Windows.

Comment: You actually have to use the `--js-flags` option to pass flags to the V8 engine: `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --js-flags="--max_old_space_size=8192"`

Comment: @Luc is there any way to verify which syntax is correct? Also, is  "--args" documented someplace? i don't see it here https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @johnywhy `--args` is how to pass flags from OSX's `open` command to the process being opened: https://brettterpstra.com/2014/08/06/shell-tricks-the-os-x-open-command/#other-handiness

Comment: @ericsoco Cool. Would be helpful if Luc mentioned "Mac"

Comment: Where is the source for the number of 1.4GB limit for 64bit systems? In Google Chrome 64bit it seems to be possible  to use >1.4. GB without the flag. 
window.performance.memory
MemoryInfo {totalJSHeapSize: 1689589628, usedJSHeapSize: 1656606844, jsHeapSizeLimit: 4294705152}

Comment: @Stefan true the limit on x64 is outdated. According to the flags defined in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/0cad8a53c8aa7d072419a42c3d26745386210ef9/src/flags/flag-definitions.h#L929,  `max_old_space_size` now defaults to 0. I tested a default node v12.20.0 installation and it fails to allocate at around 2GB. Btw I was just referring to the max memory per tab/v8 process not the total usage across all tabs which is the output of `window.performance.memory`.

Comment: [there is no 4Gb per tab limitation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1081316)

Comment: On Windows, that's `chrome.exe --js-flags="--max_old_space_size=1024"`.

Answer (score 19):

Aggregated answer based on Mihai Tomescu's answer and other resources:

1. Maximum memory per tab seems to be about 1.8GB when running a x64 Windows OS, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34667584/2780791)
2. Increasing tab memory works fine by changing Chrome link address from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`" to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --max_old_space_size=4096`

The difference can be quickly tested using [this huge image](http://wallpapersafari.com/w/UrvL4y/) which will crash Chrome using default memory settings (*Google Chrome ran out of memory while trying to display this webpage*), but will render fine after increasing the memory limit.

Comment: Here is how to open the chrome with a different user add flag ```--profile-directory="Profile 7"```
you can get the profile directory by going to ```chrome://version``` and locate the **profile path**   code    `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --max_old_space_size=4096 --profile-directory="Profile 7"`

Comment: did something change with the "huge image"? I just opened it and didn't increase the memory.

Comment: @AngelaP Yes, it is no longer visible on their website and you have to download the big version. I will try to replace this with a relevant resource.

Answer (score 8):

It seems --max_old_space_size does not work anymore.
I tested on Ubuntu 22.04 (Version 106.0.5249.119) where it did nothing, and I found [this thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/174889666/increasing-the-memory-limit-on-chrome-v104?hl=en) on Google Support saying it was removed in Chrome 104.

On Ubuntu 23.04, it still does not work but the limit seems to be above 4Gio at least on my laptop.

Here is how to check it for yourself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Author" content="Laurent LYAUDET">
  <meta name="Publisher" content="Laurent LYAUDET">
  <meta name="Description"
    content="Check if Chrome still limits tab memory">
  <meta name="Keywords"
    content="debug Chrome">
  <title>All your memory are belong to us! XD</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Check if Chrome still limits tab memory</h1>
  <p>
  Step 1: Open Chrome with command line in incognito mode
  to avoid messing with your profile (adapt this line to your OS):
  <pre>
  /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito --max_old_space_size=4096
  </pre>
  </p>
  <p>
  Step 2: Open Chrome Task Manager to check your memory (Menu > More Tools > Task manager)
  </p>
  <p>
  Step 3: Look at how much RAM used it crashes.
  </p>
  <p>
  Step 4: Repeat from step 1 with --max_old_space_size=1024.
  Currently "Version 112.0.5615.165 (Build officiel) (64 bits)",
  max_old_space_size seems to do nothing.
  Webpage loads fine with both if fine_tune_me = 400000.
  Webpage crashes with both if fine_tune_me = 1000000.
  </p>
  <script>
  // let fine_tune_me = 400000; // This value should be ok if you have enough RAM.
  let fine_tune_me = 1000000; // This value should crash.
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    for(let i = 0; i < fine_tune_me; ++i){
      let myTextArea = document.createElement("textarea");
      myTextArea.textContent = "All your memory are belong to us!";
      document.body.appendChild(myTextArea);
    }  
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it still not supported? can you please confirm.

Comment: Yes, it still seems to do nothing BUT now the hard coded limit is at least 4Gio it seems.

Comment: It doesn't work on other platforms as well since Chrome 104, I reproduce this problem under Windows 11 too with Chrome 115.0.5790.171

Answer (score 1):

> I don't believe electron has a hard limit of 4gb.  That may be its
> default, but I've been able to get to 16gb by doing the following in
> main.js:
>
> ```
>   const { app } = require('electron');
>   app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=16384');
> ```
>
> Unfortunately no such switch exists for the Chrome browser.

Reference:

- [Issue 1081316: It is time to remove the 4G/tab limitation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1081316)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. At least, it doesn't raise the `jsHeapSizeLimit` for the renderer process. I'm able to reduce the heap size limit with this command, but can't increase it.