# How to use Kepler.gl for datasets > 250 MB

Tags: react-map-gl, kepler.gl

I am using Kepler.gl to plot data . It works wonderfully and gives me the required plot. The issue is : I have very huge csv file ( 440 MB) , i read somewhere that on certain browsers like safari kepler.gl supports upto 250MB datasets but it doesn't work for chrome.

How do i import such a huge csv file ?

Answer (score 1):

The 250MB limit is an estimated browser limitation. You should be able to try a larger file with kepler.gl .

If it doesn't work, try increasing Chrome's memory: [Max memory usage of a chrome process (tab) & how do I increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491022/max-memory-usage-of-a-chrome-process-tab-how-do-i-increase-it) .