# How to paste a large input into a HTML form

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

Is there a way to input a million numbers (or higher) into a `<input type="text">` without having Chrome crash? My machine has 32GB of RAM so memory shouldn't be an issue but Chrome slows down heavily. I've tried hiding the numbers using CSS but still freezes.

Comment: You'll probably be better off with an `<input type=file>` that you drag your input file into, and use the Blob/File APIs to read the data.

Comment: What is your os? I think you need to increase your Chrome memory limit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491022/max-memory-usage-of-a-chrome-process-tab-how-do-i-increase-it

Comment: What's your use case? Pasting huge amounts of text? Automation?

Answer (score -3):

Please Try ,

```
<input type="text" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
```

you need to add style for more and more biger input and if you want to add millions of number

Chrome crashes somewhere After 8,000,000....
IE8 crashes somewhere After 8,000,000....
Safari crashes somewhere After 2,000,000....