# What's the memory limitation?

Tags: electron

I'm confused and I cannot find a solid documentation about Electron memory limitation. Is it `4 GB`? Is it `~1.7 GB`? Can anybody introduce some references? Thanks.

#### Update

It is claimed that modern Electron has ***no*** memory hard limit and it can be increased by flags as far as needed. The bundled Chromium with Eelctron is modified in a way that ***no*** hard limit is set.

Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe electron on it's own has a memory limitation from the research I did. However, based on the fact that to increase the max memory usage you have to use the `js-flags` then add `--max-old-space-size=new memory size`, I believe this is something linked to chromium and by default the max memory on chromium is, according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491022/max-memory-usage-of-a-chrome-process-tab-how-do-i-increase-it#:%7E:text=The%20limit%20can%20be%20raised,the%20shortcut%20path%20in%20Windows.), 4 GB on 64-bit machines and 1 GB on 32-bit machines.