# Confusion about sending a 100GB file from front-end to back-end

Tags: javascript, browser, memory-limit

## Background

We know that web browsers have memory [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32671934/3405291) per tab, which can be raised to `4GB` for example.

Assume there is a web app. This web app cannot load files larger than around `4GB` in its memory. If there is a `100GB` file, it cannot be loaded by the web app onto the memory.

## Approach

I'm going to send a `100GB` file from front-end to the back-end by [this approach](https://medium.com/@aresnik11/how-to-upload-a-file-on-the-frontend-and-send-it-using-js-to-a-rails-backend-29755afaad06). Basically, the user is prompted to select the `100GB` file from her/his computer:

```html
<form class="upload">
   <input type="file" name="uploadFile" accept=".stl" required />
   <br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The file is sent from front-end to back-end by a POST request using `fetch` API:

```js
const uploadForm = document.querySelector('.upload')

uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   let file = e.target.uploadFile.files[0]
   let formData = new FormData()
   formData.append('file', file)
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload_files', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
   })
   .then(resp => resp.json())
   .then(data => {
      if (data.errors) {
         alert(data.errors)
      }
      else {
         console.log(data)
      }
   })
})
```

## Question

I didn't test the above approach with the actual `100GB` file. But before testing, I wonder if I'm missing something with the above setup? Is something wrong with it? Is there a standard approach to so such things? Is there a better approach?

How can I avoid loading the `100GB` onto the JS memory? How can I send it to the back-end without going beyond the browser memory limitations?

Comment: The approach using `FormData` does not load the file into memory. Instead the browser will stream the file from disk directly to your network card. The browser will use some memory for buffering, typically around 4kB or around the size of your MTU (typically 1.5kB but can be up to 64kB). As you can see, the memory used is far less than one megabyte.

Comment: @slebetman Alright. I think I got my answer :) Thanks.

Comment: @slebetman Can you post your comment as answer? So that this question can be marked as answered. Thanks :)