# Every other refresh causes "Aw, snap" error on Chrome, hard refresh doesn't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash, redux, react-redux

We're developing a web app with Redux using react-redux. This web app deals with a substantial amount of data. Our tester noted that every other (normal) refresh causes an "Aw, snap" error in Chrome. Refreshing at that point will reload the page, but then refreshing again will cause the crash. Hard-refreshing (ctrl + f5), which bypasses the local cache, leads to a successful refresh every time. We do some things on window unload, including `navigator.sendBeacon`, but after commenting out those things the problem persists.

Thinking that it may be an out of memory exception, I've tried memory profiling with Chrome devtools, but it disconnects when the "Aw, snap" error occurs. When the refresh is successful, I don't know how to look at the data.

I've tried the Chrome logging detailed in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728483/how-to-get-more-info-when-the-aw-snap-screen-shows-up-in-chrome) and this [Chromium wiki](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) to no avail.

What should I investigate next? What does it tell me that a hard refresh always works but a soft one fails every other time? Do I have local cache problems? Please comment if you have more questions about details with my setup.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing any code and this may not help, but something I've found helps with these obscure, one-off issues is to install [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) in addition to regular Chrome.

Comment: @Toby Thanks. Using Chrome Canary I was able to get a console error which is giving me more information on the error.

Comment: After finding the error, the new question is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004550/diagnosing-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-in-react-keyescapeutils).