# Retrieve plain text script from compiled bash script in linux vps

Tags: bash

Some time ago I made a bash script file.Then I thought it would be better to protect my file using SHC, some time later I lost the bash script file that Uncompile SHC, and now I only have a bash file that has been compiled with SHC, how can I get my original bash file Before being compiled with SHC.

I have been looking for a solution but it still cannot be resolved.Please help

I have tried troubleshooting in ([Retrieve plain text script from compiled bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408373/retrieve--plain-text-script-from-compiled-bash-script)) but after I got the segmentation Fault Core Dump, I could not find the core file in my linux directory

Comment: I have tried it bro, but I can't find the location of the core file

Comment: That's a question for a different StackExchange area. Start here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179998/where-to-search-for-the-core-file-generated-by-the-crash-of-a-linux-application