# Changing location of core dump

Tags: linux, crash-dumps, coredump, recovery

I want to change the default location of core dump files so that every time a core dump is generated ,it goes to that directory.Also, is it possible to save the dump file by the name of the crashed file in this location?

Comment: The "what happened" version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can change `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to define the pathname used to generate the corefile. For more, see [`man core`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)

example:

```
echo '/tmp/core_%e.%p' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern    # `tee' instead of > so that
                                                                   # opening happens in the
                                                                   # elevated process
```

would cause all future core dumps to be generated in `/tmp` and be named `core_[program].[pid]`

Comment: +1 for the `tee` trick ;) Note that there is also `sysctl`. Then it is `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='/tmp/core_%e.%p'`

Comment: A straightforward alternative to `tee` is `sudo bash -c "echo '/tmp/core_%e.%p' >/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern"`.

Comment: On arch I have no man entry for core :/ `No manual entry for core in section 5`

Comment: @Xerus it should be there... `$ pacman -Q --owns /usr/share/man/man5/core.5.gz` - `/usr/share/man/man5/core.5.gz is owned by man-pages 5.09-2`
maybe you need to install that package?

Comment: ah, I only had `man` installed, not `man-pages`, thanks :)

Comment: If you need to append this line in .bashrc, use `echo '/tmp/core_%e.%p' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern >/dev/null` instead. Otherwise scp would be broken.

Comment: @xnervwang definitely not! Don't put `sudo` in a `.bashrc`! There will always be a better way to do what you're trying to. In this case, add an entry in a `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` file or `/etc/systcl.conf` to make it permanent.

Comment: @mata I cannot... The dev machine is under control of my company. Any modification to the system files would be reverted periodically.

Comment: Note that on Ubuntu, the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` are periodically overwritten by an automated process, clobbering any manual changes you may have made. Instructions on how to prevent this can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/420628).

Answer (score 31):

Before following the instructions in the accepted answer, it could be good idea to check the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to see if the Redhat abrt system is in use.

```
-> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e
```

If that is in use, then you already have a pretty extensive scheme for managing core files that you would want to understand before you override it.

In a nutshell, abrt:

1. puts the core files here: `/var/spool/abrt/`
2. has a gui that is started with the command `abrt-gui`
3. augments the corefile with additional information about the failed process.
4. is configure with this file: `/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf`

One common stumbling block with using it is to change this line in the config file:

```
ProcessUnpackaged = no
```

Change that to yes to capture core files from your homebrew processes, otherwise it will only capture corefiles from programs installed by the package manager.

[EDIT to answer how to use coredump]
To examine a core dump I do this:

```
cd /var/spool/abrt/XXXXXXX
gdb $(cat executable) coredump
```

There might be a better way to so that, but gdb has served me well so I have not looked for other ways.  Just replace XXXXXXX with the folder that contains your coredump file.  The gdb command is cut and paste ready.

References:

[Redhat Book](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-abrt.html)

[CentOS Forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5962)

Comment: thanks for this info. I got the coredump file, but how to open it with abrt ?

Comment: if you are not sure about how the core file was generated, just do #file core.XYZ - this will show the command executed for generating the corefile.

Comment: In Ubuntu since 16.04, [`apport` is used the same way and saves dumps into `/var/crash/`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966407/where-do-i-find-the-core-dump-in-ubuntu-16-04lts).

Answer (score 0):

By default, a core dump file is named core or core.pid (if the file /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid contains the value 1) is created in the *current working directory*.

But the **/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern** file can be used to set to define a template that is used to name and set path for core dump files. The default value in this file is "core".

We can set the core dump file name as
**$ sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern="/tmp/%e_core.%p"**
When our application crashes(say sleep), we would expect a file with the pattern of sleep_core.pid to appear under /tmp folder. Where %e is the program name and %p is the program’s PID.