# ERROR[2034] $Z0016JB:140: Operating system error 201 while communicating with server process $Z0016NV:142

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I am installing Trafodion on the centos 7. It has installed successfully but when I am initializing it using sqlci(command interface) for DB query then I am getting below errors on the console.

[image]

I goggled so much but not able to find anything related to these errors.
Could anyone help me how can I resolve these errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Trafdoion cannot support CentOS 7.0 , please wait for a while, currently, CentOS 7.0 support is under code review.

Comment: Thanks Ming. I have found the same so now I will try this on CentOS 6. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes for this.

One is operating system limits. Look at the output of the

```
ulimit -a
```

command, especially at max user processes. Maybe the operation exceeded the number of allowed processes on the system.

Another possibility is that some environment variable isn't set up. There is a file sqenv.sh in the directory where you installed Trafodion. Source that file int the .bashrc of the trafodion user:

```
source <directory where you installed trafodion>/sqenv.sh
```

After sourcing the sqenv.sh file, try this:

```
which tdm_arkesp
```

This should resolve to a process name. Try running this process and see whether you get a more detailed error message:

```
tdm_arkesp
```

Let us know what happened and I hope we can give you a solution. If you prefer a pre-installed machine image with Trafodion, there are images available for [Oracle VirtualBox](https://esgyn.com/developers/), [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B018RBMFG0), or [Docker](https://esgyn.com/apache-trafodion-on-docker-hub).

Comment: Hi @Hans, I tried with your solution and when I am sourcing the sqenv.sh file it is showing error message. ** "bash: ./sqenvcom.sh: No such file or directory" **.

And when I tried to sqenvcom.sh file in the same folder then I am getting another error .

Please find the link to open the screenshot for the same :

https://s3.postimg.org/fpfofk3zn/error.png

Comment: I have opened .bashrc file of the trafodion user. sqlenv.sh has already been sourced in this. Please find the screenshot for the same in the link :
https://s4.postimg.org/pxx2167bh/bashrc.png

Comment: @ankit, could you try the following:

    `sudo su trafodion`
   `cd /usr/hdp/current/trafodion/apache-trafodion_server-2.0.1-incubating`
    `source ./sqenv.sh`

Comment: @ankit, did you check ulimit and did you try to run the tdm_arkesp process manually as well?

Comment: I checked for ulimit and please find the link for screenshot : https://s3.postimg.org/t96x0g20z/ulimit.png 

and as you suggested I switched to trafodion user and go to the trafodion server root director and sourced sqenv.sh file. Now I didn't get any error and successfully sourced the file. After that I ran tdm_arkesp file but I got an error while run the file. I think it requires some arguments. Could you please let me know what arguments are required to pass. Please find the screenshot for the error : https://s10.postimg.org/lrdphrbk9/tdm_arkesp.png

Comment: Thanks for trying those two things, @ankit. The ulimit -a output looks good, similar to what I have on my machine. Running tdm_arkesp was just a test whether it had any issues loading DLLs. Getting the error shown in the picture shows that you were able to load and start this process successfully. So, two possible causes for your problem are now eliminated, we have to find some other possible reasons. Ming_Liu has already commented that CentOS 7 is not yet supported, that is coming in the next Trafodion release, I think. If you are running CentOS 7, you may need to try CentOS 6.7 instead.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thanks for your efforts. As I have checked the provisioning doc it has mentioned that current trafodion release tested with CentOS 6.5,6.6 & 6.7 only. This point I have missed before installation.
I will install CentOS 6 on the machine and will try the same. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I need to use trafodion dialect. I have seen that Esgyn developed trafodion dialect. Could you please let me know how can I get this. Is this paid version ?

Comment: Hi Ankit, are you referring to the SQL dialect? You can find a description of the Trafodion SQL dialect on the [Trafodion web site](http://trafodion.apache.org/documentation.html). If you want to try EsgynDB, which is based on Trafodion, you can get that on the [Esgyn website](https://esgyn.com/developers). That site has four options, choose "Run the EsgynDB sandbox on your PC" to get a version of EsgynDB, using Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: I want to use Trafodion with Hibernate but there is no Trafodion dialect available in Hibernate but Esgyn has developed Trafodion dialect with Hibernate so how can I get that dialect or jar something like that ?

Comment: Hi Hans, When trafodion is running it is generating some **core.SOME_ID** files in the $MY_SQROOT directory. Could you please let me know how can I stop to generate that files because it takes all space of the node when lots of files generated.

Comment: Hi Ankit, you can disable cores or limit their size with the ulimit command: ulimit -c 0. You could put this into the ~/.bashrc file of the trafodion user. Alternatively, you could edit /etc/security/limits.conf. Also, could you file a JIRA for the problem you are seeing?

Comment: To file a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues), you would need the stack trace. Here is how to find the stack trace. First, install gdb if not yet done: `sudo yum install gdb`. Second, edit file [/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048101/changing-location-of-core-dump), to make the executable name part of the core file name. Third, after you got a new core, as the trafodion user, do `gdb  executable core-file` and display the trace with the `bt` command.