# How to change PostgreSQL 12 crash dump location path?

Tags: postgresql

We are using Postgres 12 (TimescaleDB) and managing it through Patroni.

There was some unexpected issue that happened and crash dump written in the default location `/var/crash/_usr_lib_postgresql_12_bin_postgres.111.crash`, and this, in turn, caused a root disk full.

I looked around so many ways how to change this location but couldn't succeed.

Would you please someone help with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048101/changing-location-of-core-dump)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Am specifically looking for Postgres but your referral is for Linux core dump. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all postgresql must be configured with e.g. in `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_ctl.conf`:

```
pg_ctl_options = '--core-files'
```

if you remove the `-c/--core-file` [flag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) no core dump will be produced (not good for issue diagnosis).

By default `postgres` writes core dump to data directory path.

Check you current `kernel.core_pattern` configuration:

```
$ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = core
```

You can specify multiple variables that gets substituted:

- `%p` - pid
- `%%` - output one '%'
- `%u` -  uid
- `%g` -  gid
- `%s` - signal number
- `%t` - UNIX time of dump
- `%h` -  hostname
- `%e` -  executable filename

It's good idea to include at least `%p` (pid) in the path, in order to distinguish between consequent crashes.

```
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='/tmp/core.%e.%p'
```

in order to persist the change after reboot add the config e.g. to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core.%e.%p
```