# Core Dump - non-existing file

Tags: c, coredump

I've made a program with a segmentation fault and i want to get the core dump file but it seems that the file is not on the current directory. I've read and follow these instructions:
[core dumped - but core file is not in current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory)
but I'm still unable to get the core file.

I've tried this:

```
ulimit -c unlimited  
ulimit -S -c unlimited
```

I've also edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` the line:

```
*               soft    core            10000
```

(it was 0 the default value)

And as my system runs `apport` so I've searched `/var/crash` and the file I wanted (that should've generated) wasn't in there.

More useful information:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c
```

So what did I miss? I still don't get the core file after the segmentation fault or if I do I don't know where he is going to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory?rq=1

Comment: That's the link i've put for the instructions i've followed. As i couldn't get help from there i didn't wanted to expose my case in a comment

Comment: After you run your ulimit commands, what core size limit is reported?

Comment: $ ulimit -a           core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
And max memory size also unlimited. (Don't know if this last one helps)

Comment: Further information: When i had this issue i was on ubuntu 13.04 and i was having some errors doing the upgrade to 13.10. So I've done an upgrade through the live cd. After this, I still don't get the dump files. Any help? Thank you