# mktime and localtime causing Segmentation fault, how to properly initialize?

Tags: c, time.h

I have the following function that is repeatedly called within a larger program:

```
double troublesome_function() {
time_t time_ini = time(NULL);
struct tm tm_ini = *localtime(&time_ini);

(...)

time_t secs_passed;  
secs_passed = mktime(&tm_ini);

double return_value =0;

return_value = (double)secs_passed;

return(return_value); 
}
```

Most of the time, it works just fine. But in a few cases the line `*localtime(&time_ini)` causes a Segmentation Fault. Removing this initialization from `tm_ini` seems okay, but then the code will again run fine in most cases but the line `mktime(&tm_ini)` will cause a segmentation fault. Finally, the return operation may also be at error, which I've checked by adding `printf`s to the code.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519450/3007075) *"One gotcha with `localtime` is the returned pointer is a pointer to a static global var and subsequent calls to `localtime` update the var."*

I'm suspicious that the repeated calls to `mktime` are causing this behavior, so by adding a static counter variable, this happens at the 94th call.

Any way to prevent functions from `time.h` from suffering this interference?

Comment: Note that [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) can fail, and return a null pointer. Think bout what happen when you dereference a null pointer.

Comment: My understanding is that you have a problem if you call the function from different threads, so you have a race condition. Suggestions: you can use localtime_r if you are working on posix, and localtime_s if you are on windows. You can use use a #ifdef to conditionally enable them and wrap them all in a function to provide a somewhat portable alternative. Caution: the 2 functions require the same inputs but swapped. Caution 2: it looks like C11 has localtime_s (called as Windows) but with the input order to localtime_r .

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts : I need to implement a solution for both windows and linux, so thanks for indicating both `localtime_r` and `localtime_s`. Nonetheless, this seems to solve the issue with `localtime`, but alter on I still get the problem on `mktime`.

Comment: @Mefitico then, most likely, is as "Some programmer dude" says: localtime return a NULL, you might want to add a check to validate the idea.

Comment: `localtime_s` is added in C11, so it should work on linux too, or any C11 compiler.