# Strange glibc detected free() invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, glibc

I realise that there are a lot of questions on so with this error

```
    *** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000bde130 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ec66)[0x7f2d1f33fc66]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x23)[0x7f2d1fc31c13]
/usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug[0x4023b7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f2d1f2e278d]
/usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug[0x402109]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00415000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1061803                            /usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug
00614000-00615000 r--p 00014000 fc:00 1061803                            /usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug
00615000-00616000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 1061803                            /usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug
00bde000-00bff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f2d1f2c1000-7f2d1f476000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 275257                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2d1f476000-7f2d1f676000 ---p 001b5000 fc:00 275257                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2d1f676000-7f2d1f67a000 r--p 001b5000 fc:00 275257                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2d1f67a000-7f2d1f67c000 rw-p 001b9000 fc:00 275257                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2d1f67c000-7f2d1f681000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2d1f681000-7f2d1f696000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 262189                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d1f696000-7f2d1f895000 ---p 00015000 fc:00 262189                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d1f895000-7f2d1f896000 r--p 00014000 fc:00 262189                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d1f896000-7f2d1f897000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 262189                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d1f897000-7f2d1f992000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 275262                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f2d1f992000-7f2d1fb91000 ---p 000fb000 fc:00 275262                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f2d1fb91000-7f2d1fb92000 r--p 000fa000 fc:00 275262                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f2d1fb92000-7f2d1fb93000 rw-p 000fb000 fc:00 275262                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f2d1fb93000-7f2d1fc75000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1054000                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f2d1fc75000-7f2d1fe74000 ---p 000e2000 fc:00 1054000                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f2d1fe74000-7f2d1fe7c000 r--p 000e1000 fc:00 1054000                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f2d1fe7c000-7f2d1fe7e000 rw-p 000e9000 fc:00 1054000                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f2d1fe7e000-7f2d1fe93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2d1fe93000-7f2d1feb5000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 275249                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2d200a8000-7f2d200ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2d200b2000-7f2d200b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2d200b5000-7f2d200b6000 r--p 00022000 fc:00 275249                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2d200b6000-7f2d200b8000 rw-p 00023000 fc:00 275249                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffe2f9f000-7fffe2fc0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffe2ffe000-7fffe3000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Before I post up a load of code, I'll try to explain what I find strange about it...
I compile my program (4 .cpp files and 3 .h file) with g++ and 95% of the time it runs fine.
It parses .obj files and writes out to my own binary format .bob.
On files where this error occurs it is consistent for the exact same call to it eg.

```
root@DevVm64-Liam:/# /usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/uploads/3dmodels/3/24/sample\ obj\ file.obj
```

However for any file that fails, changing the input file name's length makes it run fine eg.

```
root@DevVm64-Liam:/# /usr/bin/obj_to_bob_debug /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/uploads/3dmodels/3/24/sample\ obj\ file1.obj
```

but changing the file name so that it is the same length the error will occur.

This happens regardless of [properly escaped] spaces in the file name.

Rather that posting up a load of code (I have no idea where in my code the error is occuring) Can anyone suggest why this might be happening? 
If necessary I can try to cut out the bulk of the code and post up the possible areas it could be happening.

Note: I never call free or delete as I only use one or two auto_ptr

Ive a feeling but I'm not sure that theres a problem with this bit of code

```
    string outFile;

    //if no output file given set to same as input file with obj replaced with bob
    if (argc == 2) {
        char* tempOutFile = new char[fineName.length()];
        strcpy(tempOutFile, (fileName.substr(0, fileName.length()-4) + ".bob").c_str());
        outFile.assign(tempOutFile);
        delete tempOutFile;
    } else {
        outFile = argv[2];
    }
```

I've been reading that there can be problems with strcpy but I don't see any problems with the code...

Comment: Surely if it's getting killed like this you have a coredump to analyse in a debugger?

Comment: where might i find this? I dont do much c++ development...

Comment: Typically it goes in the same directory as the binary you're running. Check out ulimit to ensure core dumps are allowed. When it does this you can load the core dump into the debugger along with your application and then do a stack trace to see what caused the double free, which may even be you misusing a library, not necessarily your code directly. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-current-directory You can also set MALLOC_CHECK_ as an environment variable to crash out an app early, which is very useful in this sort of scenario.

Comment: try compiling it with `-ggdb3 -O0` and run it in `valgrind` (`$ valgrind your-prog your-args`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is an undefined behaviour. `strcpy` is copying to an uninitialized pointer.

```
char* tempOutFile; // = ???
// now your copying from the sub-string to an unknown memory address
strcpy(tempOutFile, (fileName.substr(0, fileName.length()-4) + ".bob").c_str());
```

All of this to simply copy the substring to another string? Just do so:

```
string outFile;

//if no output file given set to same as input file with obj replaced with bob
if (argc == 2) {
    outFile = fileName.substr(0, fileName.length()-4) + ".bob";
} else {
    outFile = argv[2];
}
```

Also, don't forget that name use to call the program is stored in `argv[0]`. So if `argc == 2`, your program really has only one argument, `argv[1]`.

```
     $ ./prog arg1 arg2
argv   ^-- 0  ^--1 ^--2
argc == 3 (size of argv)
```

Comment: sorry just to note i changed the code to 
char* tempOutFile = new char[fineName.length()];
and was getting the same problem

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. 
Im getting confused with std::strings c strings and char arrays

Comment: re your edit. I know that yeah. expecting the input file as argv[1] and the output file can be specified in argv[2].

Comment: @user1711383 If you're still confused about sting vs char pointers, try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c