# Where do i find the core dumped file in Linux when I Quit a running command with [Cntrl + \]?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel

when I Quit a running command with `Cntrl + \`  it shows `\Quit (core dumped)` and it may create a core file containing the memory image of the program. But where do I find that file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Unix and Linux operating systems should, instead be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process dumps core, the process configured in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` is executed, from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-the-current-directory).

If your init process is systemd, you should find such content of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file:

```
|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e
```

From [systemd-coredump](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html) we can read that:

> By default, systemd-coredump will log the core dump including a backtrace if possible to the journal and store the core dump itself in an external file in /var/lib/systemd/coredump.

The core dump should be accessible in your system journal and in the `/var/lib/systemd/coredump` directory by default.

Example of coredump after sending `SIGQUIT` signal to `sleep infinity` on my system:

```
$ journalctl COREDUMP_SIGNAL_NAME=SIGQUIT
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-05-19 10:51:52 CEST, end at Sun 2019-09-01 18:14:43 CEST. --
wrz 01 18:03:32 chors systemd-coredump[24169]: Process 24167 (sleep) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                               Stack trace of thread 24167:
                                               #0  0x00007fd96c53c338 __nanosleep (libc.so.6)
                                               #1  0x000055fb279394a5 n/a (sleep)
                                               #2  0x000055fb279392a1 n/a (sleep)
                                               #3  0x000055fb27936221 n/a (sleep)
                                               #4  0x00007fd96c499ee3 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                                               #5  0x000055fb279362fe n/a (sleep)
```

More output is available when using different output options with journalctl.