# Specify location of core file

Tags: java

I have a java program (Kafka) which sometimes generate core in user's home directory. I want to specify different path for core file generation (in case it is generated) for this program only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please show the code that generates the file

Comment: Are you talking about a core dump generated by the operating system when a process crashes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-the-current-directory

Comment: What do you mean by "core file"?

Comment: @Thilo yes. Thread mentioned doesn't allow me to set core file location for only one process.