# ulimit -c unlimited does not generate a core file in c++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-18.04

When I get a segmentation fault (core dump) in a c++ programm I don't get the core file after type the command: `ulimit -c unlimited`.

It is the first time that I see that, and I do not why.

Could you help me?

Comment: What's does `ulimit -c` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at the content of:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

… which enables the system to store your core file as a given name and/or behind a given path, and even pipe it to a command if needed.

Check out this entry too :
[Core dumped, but core file is not in the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-the-current-directory)