# Can gdb automatically attach a process on a SIGSEGV

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

I have a faulty program that when execute receive a SIGSEGV.

I can use gdb like this:

```
$ gdb ./prog
```

But I would prefer that gdb catch the SIGSEGV from `prog` and attach it automatically.

```
$ ./prog
Segmentation Fault
(gdb) ...
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hmm. You can set up a signal handler to launch the debugger with the current process. That way you can inspect the whole state "live".

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *prog=0;
void fn(int signum)
{

    char buf[256]; 
    snprintf(buf,255,"ddd %s %d",prog,getpid());
    system(buf);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    prog=argv[0];
    signal(SIGSEGV,&fn);
    int *p=0; 
    int k=*p;
}
```

UPDATE: Chaged according to the suggestions of miedwar and Fanatic23. Current Ubuntu distributions are configured to disallow debugging of non-child processes. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process for a fix.

Comment: +1 good to know you can catch this signal, btw, you need an exit() after system() so it won't be called more than once.

Comment: The prototype for fn needs an integer argument to get the code compiled.

Answer (score 4):

Well you can always create a core file and then analyse the callstack using gdb on that core. You can check out the man page for ulimit to do so.

[Check this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/generate-a-core-dump-in-linux).

Answer (score 3):

To add to Mainframe's answer you can link your app with [libdebugme](https://github.com/yugr/libdebugme) (or simply `LD_PRELOAD` it) to achieve similar functionality. For example:

```
DEBUGME_OPTIONS=handle_signals=1 LD_PRELOAD=libdebugme.so ./app
```