# How to generate core dump file in Ubuntu

Tags: c, coredump

I would like to know how to generate a core dump file in Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 8.04.1 and gcc compiler 4.2.3. I have written a simple C program to generate a core dump. I have compiled the program as in --   gcc -g badpointer.c . When I run the program its gives segmentation fault but no core dump is generated. What additional things do i have to do to generate a core dump file ?

Answer (score 66):

#### Linux

Activate your coredumps by the following command:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Also, check the `core_pattern` value by:

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern
```

to see where your dumps are created (`%e` will be the process name, and `%t` will be the system time).

You can change it in /etc/sysctl.conf and then reload by `sysctl -p`.

You can test it by:

```
sleep 10 &
killall -SIGSEGV sleep
```

If core dumping is successful, you will see “(core dumped)” after the segmentation fault indication. Otherwise double-check your `ulimit`s again.

See also:

- [How to generate a core dump in Linux on a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17965/55075)
- [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77005/55075)

---

**Ubuntu**

If you've Ubuntu, your dumps are created by [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) in `/var/crash`, however it's disabled by default.

For more details, check: [Where do I find the core dump in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/966407/78223)

---

#### macOS/OS X

In macOS, crash dumps are automatically created by [Crash Reporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Reporter) in form of backtraces.
You can find these crash files by executing [Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28OS_X%29) and going to 'User Diagnostic Reports' section (under 'Diagnostic and Usage Information' group) or you can locate them in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`.

The actual core files are generated in `/cores`.

Read more: [How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412156/how-to-generate-core-dumps-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: with `sleep 10 & killall -SIGSEGV sleep` howto add options to repoen or keep closed app?

Comment: @e-info128 Once the process died of SIGSEGV signal (basically crashed), you cannot reopen it. You need to start a new process again unless it's a service, so it can respawn automatically.

Answer (score 36):

Check the ouput of `ulimit -c`, if it output 0, this is why you don't have core dumped.

Use

`ulimit -c unlimited`

to allow core creation (maybe replace `unlimited` by a real size limit to be more secure) .

Answer (score 0):

Set a max core dump size with `ulimit -c`*SIZE*.