# Segmentation Fault, no core dump

Tags: c++, c, linux, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am consistently getting a segmentation fault in my program, yet no core dump files are generated.  ulimit shows a value of unlimited, did ulimit -c unlimited just to be sure, and it appears to be fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Mayby show us some code first?

Comment: It's most likely a null pointer or accessing outside an array.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger, so that you will break when the fault happens.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at proper place? Do you have enough room on that filesystem?

Comment: Seems to be shell-dependent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/generate-a-core-dump-in-linux

Comment: @unwind it is not always possible to run a program under debugger. Also program may crash sporadically, ie once per week. Good luck catching that under debugger.

Comment: @Slava Yes, but the question says "I am consistently getting [...]", hence my suggestion.

Comment: @BartFriederichs setting limits syntax is shell dependent, how they are handled is not.

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732983/core-dump-file-is-not-generated/18428840
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232/how-to-generate-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu/18428730
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes

Answer (score 7):

if your program runs as root (or with root capabilities) check:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable`

or if program is a daemon check:

`getsebool allow_daemons_dump_core`

and to allow daemons dump core:

`setsebool -P daemons_dump_core 1`

Comment: My `/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable` puts out `2`, and I cannot find `getsebool`. What can I do?

Comment: @AlejandroGalera From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html "Between kernels 2.6.13 and 2.6.17, the value 2 was also permitted, which caused any binary which normally would not be dumped to be dumped readable by root only; for security reasons, this feature has been removed."

Answer (score 3):

There could be several reasons

- no write access to the directory
- the program changes the working directory
  look for the core in other places too
- disk is full
- ulimit is set in one shell and the program is started in a different shell or environment

Comment: +program is a daemon, but OP changes ulimit setting for his current shell session.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the shell session issue, providing you don't object to being root to test:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // Enable core dumps
    struct rlimit corelim;

    corelim.rlim_cur = -1;
    corelim.rlim_max = -1;

    if (setrlimit (RLIMIT_CORE, &corelim) != 0)
    {
        log_error ("Couldn't set core limit");
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Can you explain the code? It is a C code, right?

Answer (score -6):

the segmentation fault occurs especially that you access the wrong address in memory. It is very possible to have a resource improperly initialized. For example, you can use Valgrind for debugging.

Comment: How does this address the problem of no core dump being generated?

Comment: The problem of allocation memory is not a syntax error.