# Where is the core dump dropped when a haskell compiled program fails?

Tags: haskell, coredump, ffi

So I'm attempting to write a Haskell library using FFI bindings. I seem to have messed up somewhere and I'm getting seg faults:

```
$ cat test.input| ./dist/build/test-fftsStub/test-fftsStub
Cases: 1  Tried: 0  Errors: 0  Failures: 0got here
now here
ran init
ran execute
[1]    12406 done                              cat test.input | 
       12407 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./dist/build/test-fftsStub/test-fftsStub
$
```

It says that the core has been dumped...but I can't find it anywhere on disk. There is no core file:

```
$ ls -1 | grep core
$
```

Now I tried to raise the ulimit for my terminal which works for C core dumps:

```
$ulimit -c unlimited    
$ cat test.input| ./dist/build/test-fftsStub/test-fftsStub 
Cases: 1  Tried: 0  Errors: 0  Failures: 0got here
now here
ran init
ran execute
[1]    12694 done                              cat test.input | 
       12695 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./dist/build/test-fftsStub/test-fftsStub
$ ls -1 | grep core                                       
cabal-test-run-with-ext-core-flag.out
$
```

Question: Where is the core dumped to / how do I get the core dump?

### Successful Core Dump, now what?

Edit: Okay I have the coredump now. Turns out on Ubuntu I had to:

```
sudo service stop apport
```

So that it would not toss away my core dump. However, now how do I compare that core dump with the original Haskell code...or even the C equivalent. At this point in time I have resorted to printf debugging in the C library that I am attempting to FFI wrap.

Comment: This question is not specific to Haskell. Linux and Unix core dumps are managed by the operating system, not by the application.

Comment: So, the key question is, which operating system - and if it is not Mac OS X, which distribution?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu linux @RobinGreen and the reason that I assumed that it was related to Haskell is that running ulimit -c unlimited is usually enough to make the core dumps appear.

Comment: yes, I thought that ulimit was enough too, but in recent years that does not seem to be the case. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18428730/495796) may be useful (read all of it).

Comment: Does your program change the directory?

Comment: @Ingo My program does not change the directory. But that seems to be covered by the version of Cabal that I am using.

Comment: I have updated the question now. Does anybody know the answer to that?