# core dumb in check_match.8629 () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2

Tags: c++, c, linux

Im receving many cores from different programs on my redhat server those cores happens without any specific pattern it can happen with Tuxedo servers as well as ordinary programs the only common thing between all program is that all of them have the same top error with this **8629** number **check_match.8629 ()**

how can I identify what this number refering to?

Thanks in advance

***data from core dump file***

```
#0  0x005546b1 in check_match.8629 () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00554e17 in do_lookup_x () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x005550da in _dl_lookup_symbol_x () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00559a05 in _dl_fixup () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x0055fc90 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a library with debugging symbols to debug the core file. Once you have that, you can get a backtrace from core which will give you leads.
The number with the core file might be the PID. Check this to confirm that - [How to generate core dump file in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232/how-to-generate-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu/18428730)
or cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

Comment: is there a way to use libarires with debug without installing them as I don't have a root access and cannot run  debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686 gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.i686