# How to investigate a web performance issue which is accumulated

Tags: performance, web, playframework, resources

Our web is running on AWS with Ubuntu OS. We developed it on top of playframework. Right after the web is deployed, it is pretty quick. However, after 1 days or os, it slows down significantly. I checked resource usage of the OS, it seems normal and is responsive. Just the web service is slow to request. I suspect there are some memory, thread pool or some resource leak.  Any suggestion about how to investigate it? I used 'top' and 'ps' command to look at current resource usage but they all seem normal.

Comment: As an aside: a common (but hacky IMO) way to side-step these kinds of problems in web servers is to cycle child processes every x hours so your servers never run for a whole day so leaks never get out of hand.

Comment: You should at least tag your question properly

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a core dump and then take that to you dev computer and examine it. This is not the easiest way but if you have limited access to the box this may be required.

[Create a core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232/how-to-generate-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu)

[Analyze Core Dump File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file)

Comment: The access to the box is responsive and the resource usage is ok. The memory usage is just 22% from top command.