# Debugging segmentation faults (core dumped) for big projects

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I tried to run this code [the-git-link] (https://github.com/DropIn/SequentialTextReading), but I experience a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Do you have any idea about this error? I am running it on Ubuntu 14.4 and 
the code is too big to use traditional debug methods on it like using gdb.
Any idea how to solve this problem or what tools should i use to solve it knowing that there are many files and main in the project?

Comment: When the code breaks do you have an option to debug?  Normally you can get the stack trace from the and figure out where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Why do you say that the code is too big to use gdb ? It probably is not.

Comment: "the code is too big to use the traditional debug methods on it like using gdb " - seriously, that would have to be one huge project

Comment: compile and run under gdb, gdb will tell you the lines it failing on

Comment: well , the thing is that maybe I don't know much about the gdb but for the sake of solving the problem I read a tutorial on it , but it used the gcc with the gdb not the cmake and also I don't really know that much about the cmake too , I somehow a beginner and it's the first project that I'm trying to work on which I do it for a school project so no much experience here ....... any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can also load your coredump to gdb and find the root cause, after your program crashed.

You may benefit from reading [How to generate core dump file in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232/how-to-generate-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu), and [How to analyze a program's core dump file with gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb)