# Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel Dump File Generate (KDUMP)

Tags: linux, kernel, coredump

I want to make a Kernel Dump File (KDUMP) forcefully on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/how-to-generate-a-core-dump-in-linux-when-a-process-gets-a-segmentation-fault and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232/how-to-generate-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu

Comment: not meant the user core dump but Kernel core Dump

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood your question - to trigger a kdump vmcore collection, just ensure that `kdump-config status` is "curent state: ready to dump" and do an `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.

Same could be achieved by the use of [magic sysrq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) (`alt+prntscrn+c`)

The `kernel.sysrq` sysctl should be enabled in order to get both above working. Note that this will induce a kernel panic.

And another possibly unrelated note: stumbled upon this one while I was researching for non-working kdump collection stuck on "blue screen" on 18.04.3 LTS, so beware.

T.