# Where is my core file after segfault?

Tags: gcc, coredump

When my program segfaults, I expect a coredump but there is none. I thought just compiling with -g was enough to get a core file. Here are the gcc lines from my makefile:

```
  gcc -g -c client.c $(incdirs)
  gcc -g -o client client.o $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS) -lrt -lidn -lssl \
  /home/calls/cgi/libcurl/lib/libcurl.a  -lezxml -lxmlate $(SQLIBS)
```

All of the libraries are compiled/linked with -g as well.

And here's the gcc version info:

```
calls/cgi/client>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
```

**My question:** What more do I have to tell gcc (or anybody else) to get a core file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

it may be that the core size is set to 0.  Try

```
ulimit -a
```

if it shows

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
```

then do

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

(you may need to modify your profile scripts to change this permanently)

Comment: Thanks, that was the key. Plus I finally was forced to learn gdb (but only a little bit). So thanks for that, too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable core dump, in particular by setting the appropriate resource limit. The system call is [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) if you wanted to set it in your program. Most often, you need to set it in your shell, e.g. with `ulimit -c unlimited`

And your question is probably duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/generate-a-core-dump-in-linux) and many others.

BTW, it is usually not `gcc` which dumps core, it is your program (compiled by `gcc` or some other compiler, like `clang` or `tcc`).

Don't forget to compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g`.

And your question has many answers, you'll find thousands or more of them with Google or another search engine.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks especially for the -Wall reminder: I hate when I forget that.

Answer (score 0):

Input it like me:

```sh
➜ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = /var/crash/core-%e-%p-%t
```

And it will be found in `/var/crash`

Or maybe you should set it with`ulimit -c unlimited` if you input `ulimit -c`  it says 0