# Core dump is created, but not written to a file?

Tags: linux, coredump

I'm trying to get a core dump of a proprietary application running on an embedded linux system, for which I wrote some plugins.
What I did was:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
echo "/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
kill -3 <PID>`
```

However, no core dump is created. '/tmp/cores' exists and is writable for everyone, and the disk has enough space available. When I try the same thing with `sleep 100 &` as an example process and then kill it, the core dump is created.

I tried the example for the pipe syntax from the [core manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html), which writes some parameters and the size of the core dump into a file called `core.info`. This file IS created, and the size is greater than 0. So if the core dump is created, why isn't it written to `/tmp/cores`? To be sure, I also searched for core* on the file system - it's not there. `dmesg` doesn't show any errors (but it does if I pipe the core dump to an invalid program).

Some more info: The system is probably based on Debian, but I'm not quite sure. GDB is not available, as well as many other tools - there is only busybox for basic stuff.
The process I'm trying to debug is automatically restarted soon after being killed.

So, I guess one solution would be to modify the example program in order to write the dump to a file instead of just counting bytes. But why doesn't it work just normally if there obviously is some data?

Comment: How about /var/cache/abrt or /var/crash - is it there?

Comment: does your program have handler for the signal?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/generate-a-core-dump-in-linux/18117#18117. might be it help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your proprietary application calls [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CORE` set to 0, or if it is [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), no core dump happens. See [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html). Perhaps use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out. And you could install  `gdb` (perhaps by [cross-] compiling it). See also [gcore(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html).

Also, check (and maybe set) the limit in the invoking shell. With [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) use `ulimit` builtin. Otherwise, `cat /proc/self/limits` should display the limits. If you don't have `bash` you could code a small wrapper in *C* calling `setrlimit` then `execve` ...