# MPI Isend/Recv gets error when the size of data being received is big

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to write a C++ program by using MPI, in which each rank will send a matrix to rank 0. When the matrix size is relatively small, the code works perfectly. However, when the matrix size becomes big. The code starts to give strange error which will only happen when I use specific amount of CPUs.

**If you feel the full code is too long, please directly go down to the minimum example below.**

To avoid overlooking some part, I give the full source code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <cmath>

int world_size;
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm comm;
int m, m_small, m_small2;

int index(int row, int column)
{
    return m * row + column;
}

int index3(int row, int column)
{
    return m_small2 * row + column;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    m = atoi(argv[1]); //Size

    int ndims = 2;
    int *dims = new int[ndims];
    int *period = new int[ndims];
    int *coords = new int[ndims];

    for (int i=0; i<ndims; i++) dims[i] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<ndims; i++) period[i] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<ndims; i++) coords[i] = 0;

    MPI_Dims_create(world_size, ndims, dims);
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dims, period, 0, &comm);
    MPI_Cart_coords(comm, world_rank, ndims, coords);

    double *a, *a_2;

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        a = new double [m*m];
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
                a[index(i,j)] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /*m_small is along the vertical direction, m_small2 is along the horizental direction*/
    //The upper cells will take the reminder of total lattice point along vertical direction divided by the cell number along that direction
    if (0 == coords[0]){
        m_small = int(m / dims[0]) + m % dims[0];
    }
    else m_small = int(m / dims[0]);

    //The left cells will take the reminder of total lattice point along horizental direction divided by the cell number along that direction
    if (0 == coords[1]) {
        m_small2 = int(m / dims[1]) + m % dims[1];
    }
    else m_small2 = int(m / dims[1]);

    double *a_small = new double [m_small * m_small2];

    /*Initialization of matrix*/
    for (int i=0; i<m_small; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<m_small2; j++) {
            a_small[index3(i,j)] = 2.5 ;
        }
    }

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        a_2 = new double[m_small*m_small2];
        for (int i=0; i<m_small; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<m_small2; j++) {
                a_2[index3(i,j)] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    int loc[2];
    int m1_rec, m2_rec;

    MPI_Request send_req;
    MPI_Isend(coords, 2, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req);  
    //This Isend may have problem!
    MPI_Isend(a_small, m_small*m_small2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req);

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {

            MPI_Recv(loc, 2, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

            /*Determine the size of matrix for receiving the information*/
            if (0 == loc[0]) {
                m1_rec = int(m / dims[0]) + m % dims[0];
            } else {
                m1_rec = int(m / dims[0]);
            }

            if (0 == loc[1]) {
                m2_rec = int(m / dims[1]) + m % dims[1];
            } else {
                m2_rec = int(m / dims[1]);
            }
            
            //This receive may have problem!
            MPI_Recv(a_2, m1_rec * m2_rec, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        }
    }

    delete[] a_small;
    if (0 == world_rank) {
        delete[] a;
        delete[] a_2;
    }
    delete[] dims;
    delete[] period;
    delete[] coords;
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the code reads an input value `m`, and then construct a big matrix of `m x m`. MPI creates a 2D topology according to the number of CPUs, which divide the big matrix to sub-matrix. The size of the sub-matrix is `m_small x m_small2`. There should be no problem in these steps.

The problem happens when I send the sub-matrix in each rank to rank-0 using `MPI_Isend(a_small, m_small*m_small2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req);` and `MPI_Recv(a_2, m1_rec * m2_rec, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);`.

For example, when I run the code by this command: `mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 183`, I will get the error of

```
Read -1, expected 133224, errno = 14
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
Failing at address: 0x7fb23b485010
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node dx1-500-24164 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Strangely, If I modify the CPU number or decrease the value of input argument, the problem is not there anymore. Also, If I just comment out the MPI_Isend/Recv, there is no problem either.

So I am really wondering how to solve this problem?

**Edit.1**
**The minimum example to reproduce the problem.**
When the size of matrix is small, there is no problem. But problem comes when you increase the size of matrix (at least for me):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <cmath>

int world_size;
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm comm;
int m, m_small, m_small2;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    m = atoi(argv[1]); //Size

    double *a_2;

    //Please increase the size of m_small and m_small2 and wait for the problem to happen
    m_small = 100;
    m_small2 = 200;
    double *a_small = new double [m_small * m_small2];

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        a_2 = new double[m_small*m_small2];
    }

    MPI_Request send_req;
    MPI_Isend(a_small, m_small*m_small2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req);

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {

            MPI_Recv(a_2, m_small*m_small2, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        }
    }

    delete[] a_small;
    if (0 == world_rank) {
        delete[] a_2;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Command to run `mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 183` (The input argument is actually not used the by code this time)

Comment: If there is a segmentation fault, I'd recommend looking at the core dump to get more information about the state of the program during the crash with `gdb`. Here's how to enable core dumps (if you're on linux) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/how-to-generate-a-core-dump-in-linux-on-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: @GandhiGandhi Hi, could you have a look on my minimum example? I think there should be no segmentation fault

Comment: How much exactly in your minimum example you have to increase matrix size so that it causes problems? What are the values of `m_small` and `m_small2`?

Comment: At what values does your problem happen? MPI 3 (which is what you surely have) can only send/recv counts up to 2.14 billion.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk  Hi, 100  x 200 is enough to create the problem for me

Comment: @VictorEijkhout For the minimum example, ```m_small = 100 ``` and ```m_small2 = 200``` can creates problem for me. Actually , I am using Isend/recv, not sure if it is entirely same with send/recv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
MPI_Isend(a_small, m_small*m_small2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req);
```

`MPI_Isend` is non-blocking send (which you pair with blocking `MPI_Recv`), thus when it returns it still may use `a_small` until you wait for the send to complete (when you are free to use `a_small` again) using, e.g., `MPI_Wait(&send_req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);`. So, you then delete `a_small` while it may still be in use by non-blocking message sending code, which likely causes access of deleted memory, which can lead to segfault and crash. Try using blocked send like this:

```
MPI_Send(a_small, m_small*m_small2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This will return when `a_small` can be reused (including by deletion), though data may still not be recieved by recievers by that time, but rather held in an internal temporary buffer.

Comment: Thank you. Then why there could be different behavior regarding to the matrix size?

Comment: @JINTLG because small matrices may be copied very quickly, thus Isend completes filling temporary buffer with your data faster than you delete it.

Comment: @JINTLG is your problem resolved? If yes, please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I can mark your answer as accepted. I was waiting for an answer that handles the problem without replacing ```MPI_Isend```