# Qt application crashes at launch but running good via debbugging tools

Tags: qt, debugging, gdb, strace

All Qt GUI apps crashes with Segmentation Fault but running well via debugging tools such gdb or strace. How its can be?

```
gdb ./doomseeker
strace ./doomseeker
```

Same is with Qbittorrent

[image: 1]

and 2048-Qt

[image: 2]

Only two Qt application starting normally - CMake GUI and Audacious Qt theme

PS https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735165/debian-sid-legacy-nvidia-340-108-driver-ruins-running-qt-software

Comment: Weird. Can you generate a core dump on segfault and try to post-mortem debug it?
I'd guess it's some library loading-related race condition, but that's just a guess.

Comment: BTW, I've seen your post on the other forum. What do you expect exactly? It's either a driver/kernel or QT bug. You can try fixing that yourself, but no easy fix exists I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. How get core dump on segfault?

Comment: dmesg | grep segfault https://pastebin.com/raw/33yjKyxY

Comment: As for [core dump on segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/how-to-generate-a-core-dump-in-linux-on-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: and where is i can find coredump after segfault? or how to see it?

Comment: I am on Devuan Ceres(SySv) I get SegFault without coredumped.

Comment: Then it's setup differently, but it can be done. Why use Devuan anyway? I mean: your call, but using non-mainstream distro limits you in terms of support.

Comment: Previously i found this issue at Debian Sid and thought that Devuan have such problem but i am wrong. Here information that it happens from Qt 5.15.4 + comments
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735165/debian-sid-legacy-nvidia-340-108-driver-ruins-running-qt-software

Comment: Is there any difference if you give GDB the command `set disable-randomization off` before `r` ?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick
starting normally as usual gdb without any options